# LINQPad and T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, linqpad

How much of T-SQL, if any, does LINQPad 4.0 permit? I tried making a CTE, and it didn't work:

```
WITH foo AS (
SELECT * FROM (
VALUES (5,2),
        (6,3),
        (7,4)
) [x](id,quantity)
)
select * from foo;
```

The above gave me "There was an error parsing the query. [ Token line number =1, token line offset = 1, token in error = WITH ]".  I should clarify that I'm connected to a SQL CE database for my test - is that a limiting factor for T-SQL in LINQPad?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SQL CE does not support Common Table Expressions (but Linqpad does, if your connected to SQL server 2005 or above)